# Run-time error 2465 can't find the field '|1' with alter column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, runtime-error, alter-table

My code:

```
Private Sub UpdateTables_Click()

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    MsgBox "Please Wait for the 'Done' message to appear"
    DoCmd.RunMacro "Update_Tables"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE " & [tablename] & " ALTER COLUMN StartDateAll DATE;"
    MsgBox "Done"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

The `DoCmd.RunSQL` line is what is highlighted in the Debug window.  I started with my table name as t_tablename and got a Syntax error.  After reading I found that the "*" might be a problem so I dropped the "t*", that got rid of my syntax error but now I'm getting this 2465 error.  My column was originally "Start_Date_All", so I renamed to "StartDateAll"

I have a multiple make table queries which combines start dates for employees in various departments, the resulting combined column is text instead of date.  I have a button on a form which runs the above code to run a macro which runs the make table queries and that runs fine, but it gets stuck at this alter table part (which I just included one for test purposes)

I've checked the spelling of the column name, tried it with double quotes, also tried with "`& StartDateAll &`" ...got the 2465 error each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you said Access complains it can't find the field:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE " & [tablename] & " ALTER COLUMN StartDateAll DATE;"
```

There is a better approach, which may not solve the problem, but should at least give you a better chance to understand why it happens:

```vb
Dim strTable As String
Dim strAlter As String
strTable = "t_tablename"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
strAlter = "ALTER TABLE [" & strTable & "] ALTER COLUMN StartDateAll DATE;"
Debug.Print strAlter '<- inspect in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strAlter
MsgBox "Done"
```

I tested that code in Access 2010 with `StartDateAll`  as a text field in `t_tablename`.  The code ran without error and afterward I confirmed the field had been changed from Text to Date/Time datatype.

Key points there are:

1. Give yourself an opportunity to examine the completed `ALTER TABLE` statement you're asking the db engine to execute --> `Debug.Print strAlter`.  IOW, make sure it is what you intend.
2. Your table name, `t_tablename`, should not require bracketing.  But if you want to bracket the name, move those brackets inside the string segments.
3. Turning off `SetWarnings` suppresses information.  When troubleshooting you want every last tidbit of information you can get.  So keep `SetWarnings` on when you execute the `ALTER TABLE`.

If Access still can't find the `StartDateAll` field, double check the names of the fields which Access thinks do exist.  Here is an example from an Immediate window session:

```vb
set db = currentdb
for each fld in db.TableDefs("t_tablename").Fields : ? fld.name : next
id
StartDateAll
```

Comment: I'm giving this a try right now.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.  I'll let you know how it turns out as soon as I do.

Comment: Success!!...it turns out my make table query was still passing the column name as Start_Date_All (duh) I changed the column name in the table but when I run the code, it runs the make table query which wiped that out and reverted it to Start_Date_All.  Once I corrected my make table query this worked perfectly...whew.  Thank you again so much for the assist, it saved me a lot of headache!